# Isabelle's Code generation: Abstraction lemmas for containers?

Tags: code-generation, isabelle

I am experimenting with the Code generator. My theory contains a datatype that encodes an invariant:

```
typedef small = "{x::nat. x < 10}" morphisms to_nat small
  by (rule exI[where x = 0], simp)

definition "is_one x ⟷ x = small 1"
```

Now I want to export code for `is_one`. It seems that I first have to set up the data type for the code generator as follows:

```
code_datatype small

instantiation small :: equal
begin
  definition "HOL.equal a b ⟷ to_nat a = to_nat b" 
  instance
  apply default
  unfolding equal_small_def
  apply (rule to_nat_inject)
  done
end

lemma [code abstype]: "small (to_nat x) = x" by (rule to_nat_inverse)
```

And now I am able to define a code equation for `is_one` that does not violate the abstraction:

```
definition [code del]:"small_one = small 1"
declare is_one_def[code del]
lemma [code]: "is_one x ⟷ x = small_one" unfolding is_one_def small_one_def..
lemma [code abstract]: "to_nat small_one = 1"
  unfolding small_one_def by (rule small_inverse, simp)

export_code is_one in Haskell file -
```

**Question 1:** Can I avoid pulling the definition of `small_one` out of `is_one`?

Now I have a compound value of small items:

```
definition foo :: "small set list" where "foo = [ {small (10-i), small i} . i <- [2,3,4] ]"
```

In that form, I cannot export code using it (“Abstraction violation in code equation foo...”).

**Question 2:** How do I define an `[code abstract]` lemma for such a value? It seems that the code generator does not accept lemmas of the form `map to_nat foo = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For types with invariants declared by `code_abstract` such as `small`, no code equation may contain the abstraction function `small`. Consequently, if you want the equality test in `is_one` to be expressed on type `small`, you have to define a constant for `small 1` and prove the corresponding code equation with `to_nat` first. This is what you have done. However, it would be easier to use equality on the representation type `nat`, i.e., inline the implementation `equal_class.equal`; then, you do not need to instantiate `equal` for `small` either.

```
lemma is_one_code [code]: "is_one x ⟷ to_nat x = 1"
by(cases x)(simp add: is_one_def small_inject small_inverse)
```

The `lifting` package does most of this for you automatically:

```
setup_lifting type_definition_small
lift_definition is_one :: "small => bool" is "%x. x = 1" ..
export_code is_one in SML file -
```

Unfortunately, the code generator does not support compound return types that involve abstract types like in `small set list`. As described in [Data Refinement in Isabelle/HOL, sect. 3.2](http://www21.in.tum.de/~nipkow/pubs/itp13.html), you have to wrap the type `small set list` as a type constructor `small_set_list` of its own and define `foo` with type `small_set_list`. The type `small_set_list` is then represented as `nat set list` with the invariant `list_all (%A. ALL x:A. x < 10)`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I was expecting somehow that it will not work the way I want. I found another way to achieve what I need, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Andreas' explanation and comprehensive solution, I found a work-around that avoids introducing a new type. Assume `foo` is not used in many places, say, only in

```
definition "in_foo x = (∀s ∈ set foo. x ∈ s)"
```

Trying to export code for `in_foo` gives the "Abstraction violation" error. But using program refinement, I can avoid the problematic code:

I use `code_thms` to find out how `foo` is used and find that it is used as `list_all (op ∈ ?x) foo`. Now I rewrite this particular use of `foo` without mentioning `small`:

```
lemma [code_unfold]:
  "list_all (op ∈ x) foo ⟷
    list_all (op ∈ (to_nat x))  [ {(10-i), i} . i <- [2, 3, 4] ]"
  unfolding foo_def by (auto simp add: small_inverse small_inject)
```

(Had I defined `foo` using `lift_definition`, the proof after `apply transfer` would be even simpler.)

After this transformation, which essentially captures that all members of `foo` fulfill the invariant of `small`, the code export works as intended:

```
export_code in_foo in Haskell file -
```